# How to fill a column automatically from special values in other column?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a little issue, I have a table like this

```
ref_id |ref_name                 | ref_Type     | ref_debit
1      |BVPG Corporate 2M Spain  |              |
2      |BVPG Small 5M 54FZE      |              |
3      |BVPG Corporate 1M Spain  |              |
```

I want to fill automatically the column ref_type and ref debit.
Manually I did a substring like  (just a part of my many queries)

```
UPDATE t
SET t.ref_type = (substring(t.ref_name,6,10))
FROM ref_table t
INNER JOIN ref_table t1 on t1.ref_id = t.ref_id AND t1.ref_name LIKE'BVBG C%'
```

and if it's BVPG Corporate or a Small I have something like this

```
ref_id |ref_name                 | ref_Type     | ref_debit
1      |BVPG Corporate 2M Spain  | Corporate    | 2M
2      |BVPG Small 5M 54FZE      | Small        | 5M
3      |BVPG Corporate 1M Spain  | Corporate    | 1M
```

This is what I want and I know how to do.
But I want to make this result automatically when I have a new row.
I thought about trigger but I am using SQL Server Management Studio I don't have an idea about how to do and I don't even know if a trigger is the best solution.

I attempt something like that but it doesnt work (all row are updated even if it's begin with 'BVPG C' )

```
    if exists(
        select ref_name
        from inserted
        where ref_name like 'BVPG S%')   
      then update
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a trigger - you need a computed column (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188300(v=sql.120).aspx)). So remove your columns and add them again:

```
ALTER TABLE ref_table
ADD ref_type AS substring(ref_name,charindex(' ', ref_name) + 1, charindex(' ', ref_name, charindex(' ', ref_name) + 1) - charindex(' ', ref_name) - 1)
```

Do similar for ref_debit.

Although you would be better off doing this kind of string manipulation in your application rather than the database...

Comment: I see thank you I will try. But if I decided to include this manipulation in my application, that will not slow down the performance of my application?

Comment: It depends how you are using the computed columns. If you are going to perform searches using those values and may even index the column then it is worthwhile doing it in this way via SQL. If however you are only splitting them out in order to display those values then doing the manipulation in a language with better string manipulation performance and functionality would be preferable.